# Issues with embedding vimeo in bootstrap3 with mobile

Tags: ios, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, vimeo-player

I'm building a site and need to embed a video. I'm using bootstrap 3. Everything works great on the desktop. My issue comes in with mobile.

I SHOULD be able to just use this as my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="lead">How We Help</h2>
            <p class="lead">Confused about how bundled payments work? Meet Mary and learn what we do.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <!--DESKTOP VERSION-->
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="vid">
               <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/68729036" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
           </div> 
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With my vid div class forcing the video to be responsive and being this:

```
.vid {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.vid iframe,
.vid object,
.vid embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

However, when I do this, the desktop user is perfect but the mobile user sees a black rectangle instead of the vimeo frame with the play control and a preview slide. You can actually click the black rectangle and the video opens full screen with default behavior, but a user will never realize that this is a video, so it's not ideal.

My solution was to do the "use your own player" option. So on smaller screens, a mobile verison is called:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="lead">How We Help</h2>
            <p class="lead">Confused about how bundled payments work? Meet Mary and learn what we do. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!--DESKTOP VERSION-->
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="vid">
                <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/68729036" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div> 
        </div>

        <!--MOBILE VERSION-->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <div class="vid">
                <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/68729036" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My users now see a play button on everything, and it behaves as expected. My only issue is that with the mobile version, I've lost the ability to use a preview frame, probably because I couldn't get a preview frame to load in mobile using the regular way and it's still trickling down.

Ideally, I'd like to have a vimeo frame with a preview frame and play button in all instances. If I can't do that, I'm happy to use what I have now, but I need some way to get a preview image in the mobile version.

Thanks very much, and sorry for length!

Answer (score 0):

I wound up going this route, which I'm posting to help anyone else. My question still stands, but at least this is a workaround.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
       <h2 class="lead">How We Help</h2>
       <p class="lead extrapadding">Confused about how bundled payments work? Meet Mary      
and learn what we do.</p>
</div>


<div class="col-md-8 text-center">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 hidden-xs text-center">
  <div class="vid">
  <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/68729036" width="550" height="309" frameborder="0" 
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg text-center">
    <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/68729036" width="250" height="141" 
frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>  

</div>
</div> <!--/container-->
```